# For loop behaving when trying to clear all items asynchoronously when trying to remove all id's in an array of id's

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

When trying to clear all items with a click of a button in React with a for loop, it is acting really weird in that visually it only removes one item. However, if I refresh the page, all items are indeed removed from the UI. Does anyone know why it is behaving in such a way? I am reusing an existing redux action that usually takes one parameter at a time. That is configId. Please see the code that I implemented that is behaving like this.

```
  const clearStoppedConfigs = async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < filteredStoppedBots.length; i++) {
      for (const id in filteredStoppedBots) {
        await actions.deleteConfig(filteredStoppedBots[id]);
        ++i;
      }
    }
  };
```

BTW, the `filteredStoppedBots` above simply only contains array id's.

And here is the redux action

```
function deleteConfig(configId) {
  return {
    type: DELETE_CONFIG,
    configId
  };
}
```

And the delete api request

```
async function deleteConfig(configId) {
  const options = {
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    url: `${ALGOS_API_ROOT}/configs/${configId}`
  };
  return axios(options);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems multiple issues with `clearStoppedConfigs`, Not sure why you are iterating `filteredStoppedBots` twice, that too outer loop like array and inner loop like object. If it's just contains arrays of Id's then below code should work fine to remove multiple elements. Also incrementing `i` twice is not required too.

```
  const clearStoppedConfigs = async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < filteredStoppedBots.length; i++) {
      await actions.deleteConfig(filteredStoppedBots[i]);
    }
  };
```